# How to notify the use of cookies (Cookie Law Notice)

Tags: gdpr, website

I have been investigating **notifications about the use of cookies** and a question has come up:

Why 99.9% of websites do not report correctly about the use of cookies and **nothing happens**?

With "correctly" I mean the use of notifications where you can **deny and customize cookies**.

I have entered 20 of the top 1,000 websites (newspapers, online stores, etc) and only 1 does it correctly.

I have investigated this because I was thinking about trying to correctly inform the use of cookies on my website, and I have decided to see if others do it, and this other question has come up:

Should I use eg [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/gdpr/consent-management-solution-v2/) to have a perfect cookie usage notification but lose 15% of Google Adsense revenue?

To make the subject a little clearer, I would like to add that in the cookie policy I explain each of the types of cookies, their reasons, how to eliminate them and all that is necessary. I'm just talking about notification about its use.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks.

1%:
[image]
99% (Without personalization in the cookie policy)
[image]

Comment: Where are you finding the standards of what constitutes "correctly" notifying users about cookies? Is it in a law or regulation? If so, what law or regulation?

Comment: Yes, it is the General Data Protection Regulation (RGPD) approved by the European Parliament, where it is detailed that cookies with personal data (such as advertising or analytics) must be used after receiving the user's prior consent.

Comment: Detailed information about obtaining consent can be found in [providing guidance on obtaining consent for
cookies](https://ec.europa.eu/justice/article-29/documentation/opinion-recommendation/files/2013/wp208_en.pdf). In short, Article 5(3) of the [ePrivacy directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:32002L0058:EN:HTML) specifies that consent is required. The GDPR defines the way consent is obtained (because of [Art. 94(2) GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-94-gdpr/)).

Comment: The European Data Protection Board has issued [Guidelines 05/2020 on consent under Regulation 2016/679](https://edpb.europa.eu/sites/edpb/files/files/file1/edpb_guidelines_202005_consent_en.pdf) which clarifies the cookie consent. In particular it fully clarifies that using "scrolling a page" and so called "cookie walls" it is not possible to obtain a valid consent under GDPR.